# Working SUMPRODUCT function on Google Sheets does not work in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup, countif, sumifs

I have a function here that is meant to calculate how many leads I have in each country.

`=sumproduct($A2=(vlookup(id_leads!$A:$A,country_leads!$A:$B,2,0)))`

On sheet `id_leads`,`$A:$A` contains the lead ids

On sheet `country_leads` Column `A` contains the lead ids. Column `B` contains the country of which the lead is located.

Can someone explain why it fails in Excel (I get a #VALUE! error), but works fine in Google Sheets? A suggestion to make this formula work in Excel would be appreciated. I've tried to use COUNTIF and SUMIF, but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kindly provide an example of your data that we can copy/paste, or upload a copy of your dysfunctional workbook.  Please read the Help section of this forum about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I suspect your problem is with the `VLOOKUP` function and its first argument, but your desired results should be easily obtainable in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use COUNTIFS() wrap by SUM() in an array formula, something like:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(D:D,B1:B3,E:E,A1))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Note the 2nd and 4th criteria need to be limited to the data set and not a full column reference.

So your formula would be something like this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(country_leads!$A:$A,id_leads!$A1:$A100,country_leads!$B:$B,$A1))
```